# Highcharts Show x-axis on top

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to show the x-axis and corresponding labels on top of the graph instead of the bottom?

Inverting or reversing the data is not what I am looking for design wise.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes.  In your xAxis properties, set 'opposite:true'

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.opposite

Comment: cant believe i missed that in the api. i was just looking at the reveresed option. thanks.

Comment: Don't blame yourself this is Highcharts

Comment: This somehow didn't work for the xAxis. I can't seem to add the second x axis....

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic adding a second axis is a different question. For best results, post a new question and provide your current code or fiddle example.